# Как поставить SSL сертификат на Apache?

Tags: ssl

Сервер на apache2, как туда поставить SSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для установки SSL на ваш Ubuntu/Linux сервер необходимо иметь Private Key а так-же сертификат с рассширением crt, желательно что-бы сертификат был подписан и одобрен центроом сертификации DigiCert или похожими поставщиками. Далее будет необходимо загрузить 2 этих файла на ваш сервер, т.к ваш сервер использует nginx то папка хранения файлов с сертификатами и ключами это: /etc/apache2/ssl/

Далее будет необходимо указать путь до сертификата и ключа в конфиге сайта nginx. Затем вводите команды по очереди: "service apache2 stop" "service apache2 start" если у вас выходят ошибки по типу:[image: изображение ошибки]

Не беспокойтесь это из-за (скорее всего) частой прослушки одних или нескольких портов

Comment: Такой ответ и под вопросом про nginx был бесполезным, а эта неаккуратная и неисправленная копипаста ещё более бесполезная...